# Question about the Proof of Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to wrap my head around the proof of B-W Theorem. Everything has been smooth so far, except when it comes to this. Please note that it has been proven, by the Nest Intervals Property, that there exists some $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x\in\bigcap^\infty_{n=1}I_n$. Also, the proof supposes that there exists some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\epsilon>\text{ length of $I_n$}$. **The aim here is to prove that $x$ is the limit point of a subset $S$ in $\mathbb{R}$.**

It follows that given $\epsilon>0,$ if $y\in I_n$, then $|y-x|\leq\text{ length of $I_n$}<\epsilon$. **(Ok.)**

Therefore, the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ is a subset of $I_n$ **(Why?)**. Since $I_n\cap S$ is infinite, there exists some $y\in S$ such that $y\in S\cap N_\epsilon(x)$ with $y\neq x$. **(I don't get this.)**. Since the choice of $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $x$ is a limit point of $S$.

(Note: $N_\epsilon(x)$ is the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$.)

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: It is the other way around: $I_n$ is a subset of the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood.